# How to restart an app on a Philips Android TV?

Tags: applications, reboot, remote-control, android-tv, hard-reset

It happens every now and then that an app crashes on my Philips 65PUS9006 Android TV.
The problem is that I haven't found a way to restart the app from the Philips TV Remote.

- Is there a way to restart an app on a Philips Android TV with the help of the TV remote only?
- Alt, is there a way to completely restart Android on a Philips Android TV with the help of the TV remote only?

*I don't want to have to pull the plug out of the power outlet (like I have been doing so far), just to be able to restart an app that is not responding anymore.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @Snostorp answer I actually found a solution that works.

Here's how to force close an Android TV app:

- `Long press` the `Home button` on the TV remote.
  *This will bring up the Apps Gallery, which shows all the Android TV apps installed on the Philips Android TV.*
- From the Apps Gallery, `Highlight the app` you want to force close.
- `Long press` the `Select button` on the TV remote.
  *This will bring up a Popup Menu.*
- From the Popup Menu, `Select "Information"`.
  *This will bring up a side menu with all the information regarding the app you want to force close.*
- From the side menu `Select "Force stop"`.
- You will now be prompted to confirm the force stop, `Select "Okay"` to finish.

Congratulations, you have now succesfully force closed an Android TV app installed on a Philips Android TV.

[How To Force Close an Android TV](https://www.dignited.com/92296/force-close-android-tv-apps/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say, but it doesn't seem like it's possible to do with the current version of Android on Philips TV.

From Philips Support:
[What to do if an app in a Philips TV does not work?](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-f/XC000014771/what-to-do-if-an-app-in-a-philips-tv-does-not-work)

Comment: I'm not certain this support issue is for Philips Android TV.